# Strong parameters not whitelisting attributes with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, strong-parameters

I'm having some issues understanding how to nest 3 models. I'm trying to, at the deepest point of the relations, add a `Video` to the `WorkoutSteps` (not creating a new video but select an existing one from a dropdown)

Models:

`Workout`
`WorkoutSet`
`WorkoutStep` -> just an array of `Video`
`Video`

*Relationships*
Workout:
`has_and_belongs_to_many :workout_sets, :join_table => :workout_sessions, dependent: :destroy`

WorkoutSet
`has_and_belongs_to_many :workout_steps, :join_table => :sets_steps, dependent: :destroy`

WorkoutStep
`has_and_belongs_to_many :workout_sets, :join_table => :sets_steps`

And the following in the views:

_form.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for(@workout, url: admin_workouts_path(@workout)) do |f|
  = f.input :title
  %h3 Sets
  .sets.some{ :style => "margin-left: 25px" }
    = f.simple_fields_for :workout_sets do |set|
      = render 'workout_set_fields', f: set
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add set', f, :workout_sets
  = f.submit
```

_workout_set_fields

```
= f.label :title
= f.text_field :title
%br
%br
  #sets.some{ :style => "margin-left: 25px" }
    = f.simple_fields_for :workout_steps do |step|
      = render 'workout_step_fields', f: step
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add step', f, :workout_steps
```

_workout_step_fields

```
= f.association :main_videos, include_hidden: false
```

workouts_controller.rb

```
def workout_params
    params.require(:workout).permit(:title, :pro, :workout_step_id, workout_sets_attributes: [ :id, :_destroy, :title, workout_steps_attributes: [ main_video_ids: [:id] ] ])
end
```

Checking the params:

[image: screen shot 2016-04-08 at 8 34 51 pm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, the problem was solved as I stated on the comment above.

```
params.require(:workout).permit(:title, :pro, :workout_step_id, workout_sets_attributes: [ :id, :_destroy, :title, workout_steps_attributes: [ {main_video_ids: []} ]])
```

for more info, [check this link](https://coderwall.com/p/_1oejq/handling-has_and_belongs_to_many-checkboxes-with-rails-4-strong_parameters)

Answer (score 0):

`main_video_ids` is an array attribute, not a hash of `id`s. So you can whitelist it directly:

```
def workout_params
    params.require(:workout).permit(:title, :pro, :workout_step_id, workout_sets_attributes: [ :id, :_destroy, :title, workout_steps_attributes: main_video_ids: [] ] ])
end
```

Comment: Didn't work - tho, found a way to whitelist the `ids` but still, the models are not being created

`params.require(:workout).permit(:title, :pro, :workout_step_id, workout_sets_attributes: [ :id, :_destroy, :title, workout_steps_attributes: [ {main_video_ids: []} ]])`

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer. Are you getting the right params? Perhaps it's a validation issue? What do you get if you do `@workout.valid?`

Comment: `true` - furthermore, debugging the content everything seems to be in place, is just the save step.

http://imgur.com/BWxv5d6

Comment: I really don't want to think it's trying to create a new `Video` model and failing to save

Comment: FYI, solved - debugging in more depth did the trick, obscure problem